# How to monitor Macrium Reflect backups with Nagios?

Tags: nagios

Has anyone set up monitoring of Macrium Reflect backups using Nagios? If not that specific backup software, any general suggestions for how to set up Nagios to monitor backups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Macrium Reflect, but a general principle that I like to use with file-based backups is to use a Nagios check to verify that the backed up files have been updated within the expected time frame and are of the expected size.  I wrote a [blog post on the topic](http://optimalops.blogspot.com/2010/01/fun-with-nagios-part-2-check-yer.html) if you'd like more info.